# JavaRPN (Updated)

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, calculator

I have previously worked on this program in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226782/javarpn-calculator), and have gotten some very good answers and help! Now, I have done some more work on the program, and would love if you could give me honest feedback on what I need to change.

## Main

```java
package owl;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
        System.out.println("JavaRPN: Input numbers and operands separated by newline or space");
        while (true) {
            try {
                String input = reader.readLine().toLowerCase();
                RPNcli.parse(input, stack);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This class just gets the input and passes it into the parse class. I think I am not using the Object Oriented part here correctly, with separating the program into the Main and RPNcli classes...

## RPNcli

```java
package owl;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

public class RPNcli {

    public static void parse(String input, Stack<Double> stack) {
        String[] parts = input.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            Double num = isNumber(parts[i]);
            if (num != null) {
                stack.push(num);
            } else
                operation(parts[i], stack);
        }
    }

    private static void operation(String input, Stack<Double> stack) {
        Set<String> simples = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/", "^"));
        Set<String> functions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("sin", "cos", "tan", "asin", "acos", "atan", "sq"));
        Set<String> commands = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("p", "e", "c", "pop", "swap"));
        if (simples.contains(input)) {
            simple(input, stack);
        } else if (functions.contains(input)) {
            function(input, stack);
        } else if (commands.contains(input)) {
            command(input, stack);
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Command");
        }
    }

    private static void command(String input, Stack<Double> stack) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#########");
        switch (input) {
        case "e":
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case "p":
            if (stack.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(df.format(stack.peek()));
            } else
                System.out.println("ERROR: no stacks to peek");
            break;
        case "c":
            stack.clear();
            break;
        case "pop":
            if (stack.size() > 0) {
                stack.pop();
            } else
                System.out.println("ERROR: no stacks to pop");
            break;
        case "swap":
            if (stack.size() > 1) {
                double num2 = stack.pop();
                double num1 = stack.pop();
                stack.push(num2);
                stack.push(num1);
            } else
                System.out.println("ERROR: can't swap empty stack");
        }

    }

    private static void function(String input, Stack<Double> stack) {
        if (stack.size() > 0) {
            double num = stack.pop();
            double rads = Math.toRadians(num);
            double ans = 0;
            switch (input) {
            case "sq":
                ans = num * num;
            case "sin":
                ans = Math.sin(rads);
                break;
            case "cos":
                ans = Math.cos(rads);
                break;
            case "tan":
                ans = Math.tan(rads);
                break;
            case "asin":
                ans = Math.asin(rads);
                break;
            case "acos":
                ans = Math.acos(rads);
                break;
            case "atan":
                ans = Math.atan(rads);
                break;
            }
            stack.push(ans);
        } else
            System.out.println("ERROR: can't operate on empty stack");
    }

    private static void simple(String input, Stack<Double> stack) {
        if (stack.size() > 1) {
            double num2 = stack.pop();
            double num1 = stack.pop();
            double ans = 0;
            switch (input) {
            case "+":
                ans = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "-":
                ans = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case "*":
                ans = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                ans = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case "^":
                ans = Math.pow(num1, num2);
                break;
            }
            stack.push(ans);
        } else
            System.out.println("ERROR: can't operate on empty stack");
    }

    private static Double isNumber(String input) {
        try {
            double num = Double.parseDouble(input);
            return num;
        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the input is parsed and all of the operations happen, based on the data parsed. I think maybe I could split this class into two classes called "Parser" and "Calculator". Please give me your opinion on this, I really want to learn how to do this better.

P.S. If you'd rather look at the code on GitHub or clone to run it, here is the GitHub [page](https://github.com/ViceroyFaust/JavaRPN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already said, it is a good idea separate commands from maths operations with the creation of two classes , I made two classes to give you a rough idea. In your `Main` class you can use [Try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct with your buffer, below the code

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("JavaRPN: Input numbers and operands separated by newline or space");
            RpnCli cli = new RpnCli();
            while (true) {
                String input = reader.readLine().toLowerCase();
                cli.parse(input);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see I created a `RpnCli` instance to avoid `static` method (I put static just the set of commands for possible future purposes). I updated the `RpnCli` class in the followind way:

**RpnCli.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RpnCli {
    private final static Set<String> commands = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("p", "e", "c", "pop", "swap"));
    private Deque<Double> stack;
    private Calculator calculator;

    public RpnCli() {
        this.stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.calculator = new Calculator(stack);
    }

    public void parse(String input) {
        String[] parts = input.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            try {
                Double num = Double.parseDouble(input);
                stack.push(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { 
                operation(parts[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void operation(String input) {
        if (calculator.contains(input)) {
            calculator.calculate(input);
        } else {
            if (commands.contains(input)) {
                command(input);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Command");
            }
        }
    }

    private void command(String input) { /*omitted for brevity*/ }
}
```

I divided math operations from command operations, so I created a new class `Calculator` for math operations that in its constructor has as its parameter the stack you use for all operations. You can see I used `Deque` class for variable `stack` because `Stack` java class is less complete compared to it. I also modified your `parse` method so if the input is not a `double` value will be parsed by `operation` method as you already made in your code. 
I added a new class called Calculator, below the code:

**Calculator.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Calculator {
    private final static Set<String> simples = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/", "^"));
    private final static Set<String> functions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("sin", "cos", "tan", "asin", "acos", "atan", "sq"));
    private Deque<Double> stack;

    public Calculator(Deque<Double> stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
    }

    public boolean contains(String input) {
        return simples.contains(input) || functions.contains(input);
    }

    public void calculate(String input) {
        if (simples.contains(input)) {
            simple(input);
        } else {
            function(input);
        }
    }

    private void function(String input) { /*omitted for brevity*/ }

    private void simple(String input) { /*omitted for brevity*/ }
}
```

The most important thing is this class is the field `Stack` passed by the `RpnCli` class: it will no more appear as a parameter in the methods like the methods of the containing class `RpnCli` and so there is no more need of static methods.

Comment: I know I am late, but I would like to take a look at the "contains" method. The calculate method decides if we are using simples if contains returns true. But contains will always return true if there is a function or a simple...

Comment: And when I try to use my function and simple methods, it tells me that I "cannot make a static reference to a non static field.

Comment: @ViceroyFaust, the `contains` method checks if your token is a simple or a function , if you define an instance `calc` you can call like `if(calc.contains()) {calc.calculate()}`. The error is due to the fact you have a static method and you are calling inside of it an instance calc defined outside it, so you have to remove static from method.

Answer (score 4):

### Bugs

The input to `asin`, `acos`, and `atan` is not radians.  That is the output unit.  `sin(30°) == sin(π/2) == 0.5`.   Converting the input to radians makes sense. `asin(0.5) == π/2 == 30°`.   You should call `toDegrees` on the output, not `toRadians` on the input.

Fall-through causes `"sq"` to produce `sin(rads)` instead:

```
        case "sq":
            ans = num * num;
        case "sin":
            ans = Math.sin(rads);
            break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Somehow I did not realise I forgot to put a break on sq. Also, but isn't 30 degrees to pi/2 going to produce the same output?

Comment: 30° is the number `30.0`; π/2 is the number `1.57079632679...`.  Those are quite different floating point values.  `Math.toRadians(30.0) = 1.57079...`, `Math.sin(1.57979...) = 0.5`, `Math.asin(0.5) = 1.57079...`, and `Math.toDegrees(1.57079...) = 30.0`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the clarification! I will fix that asap. @AJNeufeld